# Can I run a Contest on a Page Tab or Static html iframe app?

Tags: facebook, forms

I want to run a contest for business.
Am I able to run it on an static html iframe app or a page tab that I created through Facebook Developers or must it be a third party application?

Answer (score 0):

A Contest is a complex (not static) web app that requires development. Here are a couple of tips:

1. If you are to develop the contest then make sure you read the [guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php).
2. otherwise check one of the [Preferred Developer Consultant](http://developers.facebook.com/preferreddevelopers/), there are a bunch of nice contests apps
3. a page tab is just a holder for your "app", so yes you can have a contest in a page tab.